# TextView with permenant http://

Tags: android, webview, textview, webaddress

I'm setting up a TextView in my application that users type in a web address, and then a WebView loads it. All of this currently works, and I have it auto filling the TextView with the last used address.

I would like it to prompt the user to put in the address without the https:// by having https:// already there, bold and uneditable. I have seen this done before, but im not even sure how to start on it. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pre-set the "http://" sequence and use an InputFilter to prevent the user to delete the "http://" and to manage the text he enters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a xml namespace for that, but you can put a `TextView`in fron of the `EditText` and create an illusion like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135075/4467208)

But the real magic happens when you are reading the `EditText` which means you put the `http://` in front of it.

For example like this

```
 String url = textView.getText().toString();
 if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
     url = "http://" + url;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved my problem and the next one I would have!